# Cocos2d - follow a path when dragging an image

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to build a game using cocos2d where the user is able to drag an object along a path to a end goal. I have gotten the drag and drop to work but I am not sure how to implement the path so that when the user goes off the path it dies.

Any idea how to implement this so that I can have multiple levels?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your problem you don't want to do drag and drop at all. 
Instead make the movement along the path an action and use the user's touch to set how far along that action they are. That way (like you would scrub backwards and forwards with a video) the user can scrub the object's action along its path.

I would first of all get your object moving along the path you desire using CCBezierTo or whatever. When you are happy with the results start the touch actions.
When the user touches the object you want to know how far along the path they are where 0 is the start and 1 the end. Then move the number closer to 1 the closer to the endpoint the touch moves and closer to 0 as it moves closer to the start point. 
If you path is fairly straightish you can probably just do a simple calculation of where the touch is on a straight line between the start and end point. If its a complicated curve say going in circles you will have some hard work/trig to do!

Then as the touch moves you will need to update the object's position to the new location on the path. Say you have worked out the the touch is now at .75 along your path you will now need to workout the position the object should be at .75 * duration. You may need to extend or add a category to your action to allow you to set the position your given elapsed value.

Hope this steers you in a possible direction!